# Print a PDF to a new PDF from Acrobat preserving the ocr text

Tags: pdf, adobe-acrobat, ocr, print-to-pdf

I would like to print a protected PDF file in another PDF file using Acrobat, so that I can also consult it in the future, and I would like to keep the text searchable: is there a way to do this with Acrobat without losing the ocr?

I downloaded the file via an institutional access and the file can only be opened for 14 days via Acrobat on my PC. Of course if I print the file as a PDF normally with Acrobat all these restrictions are gone, but I lose the ability to do text searches and copy/paste text.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: I think I have focused the problem: how should I modify the question to make it more precise?

Comment: What kind of protection does the file have? Only edit protection? As a result, do you need a file without any protection? For what use?

Comment: I downloaded the file via an institutional access and the file can only be opened for 14 days via Acrobat on my PC. Of course if I print the file as a PDF normally with Acrobat all these restrictions are gone, but I lose the ability to do text searches and copy/paste text.

Answer (score 0):

That sounds like a [DRM protected](https://www.locklizard.com/pdf-digital-rights-management/) pdf file.  Acrobat itself strictly enforces DRM, but you can try one of the following. Please be aware though that you might be infringing copyrights, so only proceed if you have a legitimate reason.

1. Try to open the pdf in Firefox. The Firefox pdf plugin does not always enforce pdf protection, and you might be able to print your file as a new pdf, without any page flattening happening.
2. If you google for "pdf remove drm" you might find a service able to help you.
3. The manual method is to copy the contents and paste them in a text editor.

Comment: Unfortunately, the pdf is protected with a "p15" policy and the methods you listed won't work. For the moment I can simply print the pdf with Acrobat's virtual printer or save the pdf in word and then convert it back to pdf.